# Is it possible to learn with batch size = 1?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization, gradient-descent

Due to OOM error, I can only set the batch size to be 2 or 1.

Is it possible to learn with such a low batch size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Before mini-batching existed, SGD referred specifically to batch size equal to one.

You can actually use a bigger batch size though, you just need to add gradients from sequential samples within a batch. This is called Gradient Accumulation. See [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/gradient-accumulation-overcoming-memory-constraints-in-deep-learning-36d411252d01).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!!!